# Querying FDA Using NDC

Tags: openfda

Would someone be able to guide me on how to create the right query to find a pill's metadata based on NHC.

Here the combinations I tried but all return no results.

Identifier: 51285-0092-87_BE305F72

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_id:"51285-0092"](https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_id:%2251285-0092%22)
[https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:"51285-0092"](https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:%2251285-0092%22)
[https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:"51285-0092"](https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=packaging.package_ndc:%2251285-0092%22)

I also tried versions with the "-87" with no luck. Any help offered would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just have an extra `0` within the NDC code. Here is the right query:

https://api.fda.gov/drug/ndc.json?search=product_ndc:51285-092

Comment: By chance, is there a way that you knew this? I am trying to pragmatically account for this as I have a 4K pills that return nothing when I use the FDA api. Here are a few more examples in case it helps too:  00093-0148-01, 00093-7248-06 . I have been reading this to learn the structure of NDC code too: https://www.drugs.com/ndc.html